# Is DATA Column in MediaStore Of Android Not Deprecated Yet?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, deprecated, mediastore

I just want to know why `mediastore data is not deprecated yet` when i write in codes of android studio it does not show any warnings regarding that column. But developer site says this column (**DATA**) is *deprecated*. `Also when i run the app in android version R (api level 30) it runs without any error`.
So my question is, that is this column really deprecated or not if yes then why not yet in my emulator ?

Comment: What is your `compileSdkVersion`?

Comment: compileSdkVersion is 30

Comment: it is confusing in the official docs when this field will stop working. At some point you will need to change it, so it is better if you don't use it. In case you are already using it, you still have some time until android 11 is released and google play handles the new permission to access the filesystem.

Comment: What is your buildToolVersion?